# PHP + NetBeans Auto-complete problems

Tags: php, netbeans

I'm sure this is easy but after 2 days of searching I cannot figure it out. I had NetBeans 8.0 set up so when I typed php commands it would auto complete (or suggest other commands in a drop-down) and give me the parameters needed. For example if I wrote `$string = su` there would be a drop-down with `substr(string $string, int $start[,int $length])` , `substr_count(string $haystack, string $needle[,int $offset = 0[,int $length]])` , `substr_compare`.., etc..

My computer crashed and so I started from scratch and reinstalled php and netbeans 8.0 and can't seem to get netbeans auto completing like it was before.

I have setup the php interpreter but don't know if I need to install a plugin or if I'm missing some easy step.

Anyone with the answer would be appreciated.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/873432/netbeans-php-code-completion might be relevant.

Comment: Is `netbeans` recognizing your `php` installation? Re-check that through settings. If not, make sure that `php` is in the path variable when you start netbeans. For example, go to the command prompt and issue `php --version` to make sure it is installed, then issue `netbeans`.

Comment: @ Nathan I tried that and it did not resolve the issue. I believe that is only for those who have updated netbeans instead of php not completing on a fresh install. Thank you though

Comment: @PrahladYeri Yes, php -- version returns the version of php through command prompt. In the settings of netbeans I have php 5 interpreter set to c:\php\php.exe which is the correct location for php.exe

Comment: I read this article: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3608270/netbeans-php-code-completion-for-standard-functions

Answer (score 0):

I read this article: [NetBeans PHP Code Completion for Standard Functions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3608270/netbeans-php-code-completion-for-standard-functions)
I was opening files and not putting them into a project. Duh! Thanks for everyones help though

Comment: In all "heavy-weight" IDEs like Eclipse, Netbeans, etc. everything revolves around a "project", always remember that! Generally each type of project is associated to a particular language/framework such as `php` which tells the IDE what features to invoke for files in those type of projects.