# Why didn't netbeans auto complete PHP functions

Tags: php, netbeans, autocomplete, code-completion

[image]

I installed netbeans, but when I wrote functions like image[prepare or fetch statement], it did not autocomplete.

Answer (score 0):

netbeans has many type of [Code Completion](https://netbeans.org/kb/73/java/editor-codereference.html#codecompletion), to get suggested completion of a given function, you can use  the shortcut `ctrl+space`.

please make sure that the necessary package of your function are already imported,  and that you declare it in an appropriate code block.

*note*: the shortcut to import all the required package (given that the project has already access to them) is `ctrl+shift+i`

Comment: When i use shortcut ctrl+space the function like prepare or fetch in PDO not autocomplete

Comment: at first I was talking about java auto-completion, but I see that you are working with PHP, check this [SO question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3608270/netbeans-php-code-completion-for-standard-functions) and let me know if it helps